# Github private repository permission with key

Tags: github, permissions, repository

I am trying to find a way to give permission to private repository with some key , and not add users manually.
Just give them a private key that I need to generate and they will use it to get the permission
Is there such a way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Share the same private key.
This might (I've not checked) give access to all the repos associated with that user.
Found [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/170682/using-same-ssh-private-key-across-multiple-machines) which has some info.